# Eloquent Javascript: Understanding why array is being pulled from another array rather than just the values (listToArray function)

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object, nodes

I am reading through Eloquent Javascript and am currently on Chapter 4 working on the exercise regarding arrays to list and vice versa. The exercise wants me to get the console to print [10, 20, 30] but I am instead getting it to print [[10],[20],[30]] and am unsure why. I suppose you could argue that it doesn't make a difference, but I would like to "p

```js
function arrayToList(arr) {
  let obj = {};
  for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj.value = arr.splice(0,1);
    obj.rest = arrayToList(arr);
  }
  return obj;
};

function listToArray(list){
  let tempArray = [];
  for(var node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
    if (node.rest !== undefined){
    tempArray.push(node.value);
   }
  }
  return tempArray;
};

console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));
```

ull" the values out of the array. I attempted to created another temporary array to use the .join method and then push that into my result array, but that just gives me 1 for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
function arrayToList(arr) {
  let obj = {};
  for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj.value = arr.splice(0,1);
    obj.rest = arrayToList(arr);
  }
  return obj;
};

function listToArray(list){
  let tempArray = [];
  for(var node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
    if (node.rest !== undefined){
    tempArray.push(node.value);
    }
  }
  return tempArray;
};

console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

When you use 'obj.value = arr.splice(0,1);' you are setting the key 'value' to an array of the first element of 'arr.' I am not sure of a better way other than replacing that line with:

```
obj.value = arr.reverse().pop();
arr.reverse();
```

I feel like a better solution to your problem would be something like this:

```
function arrayToList(arr) {
    let list = {};

    arr.forEach(function (e, i) {
        list[i] = e;
    });

    return list;
}

function listToArray(list) {
    let array = [];

    for (let i in list) {
        array.push(list[i++]);
    }

    return array;
}

console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.splice()` always returns an array, doesn't matter if it's just 1 element (`[10]`) or 0 elements (`[]`). Use `Array.shift()` instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Here's a little cleanup of your code for further study:

```
function ArrayToList(array) {
    let root = {};
    // final node in the list is going to be an empty object
    // since `array.length` will evaluate to `false`
    if (array.length) { // don't need a cycle here since we're recursing
        root.value = array.shift();
        root.next = ArrayToList(array);
    }
    return root;
}

function ListToArray(root) {
    let array = [];
    while (root) { // `root` will evaluate to `false` if object is empty
        if (root.value != undefined) array.push(root.value);
        root = root.next;
    }
    return array;
}
```